# Why the unexpected result showing the results?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
function init(n) {
 console.log(n);
 setInterval(init.bind(this, ++n), 1000);
}

// init(0); // Works bad


function init2(n) {
 setInterval(function() {
 console.log(n++);
 }, 1000);
}

init2(0); // Works fine
```

The first is a *recursive function* with to a `setInterval`.

Why does the first function NOT work as *"expected"*? with "expected" I mean that every 1 second is shown `n + 1`

I have been told that it is because by calling itself, calls are multiplying more and more and overflowing memory.

This I have noticed, but I can not make the mental image of this, can someone explain it to me more detailed? My problem is that I thought that, when executing the function every 1 second, I assured myself that exactly that would happen, but no. Calls multiply and do not wait for 1000 ms.

My mental image of the flow is:

```
1 - Call init ()

2 - Show n and then add 1 to n

3 - With a setInterval, execute the init () function only if 1000 ms have 
passed.

4- 1 second passed ..

5- We return to step 1
```

Comment: Your first function is *not* recursive.  `setInterval` does not call its argument on the current call stack.

Comment: Do you know the difference between  `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Call `init()` manually. The function starts an interval that triggers once every second.
2. A second later, the interval triggers the first time and calls `init()` which starts *another* interval.
3. Two seconds later (counting from the start) both intervals trigger and call `init()`. Both function calls start a new interval. There are now 4 intervals in total.
4. Three seconds later the 4 intervals trigger and each start a new interval. There are now 8 intervals in total.

and so on until you run out of resources.

In `init2()` this doesn't happen because the interval never calls the function again and therefore there's ever only one interval running.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet is fine if you use `setTimeout` instead:

```js
function init(n) {
  if (n > 10) return; // 10 is enough in the example code
  console.log(n);
  setTimeout(init.bind(this, ++n), 1000);
}

init(0); // Works good
```

See, in your original case each call of `init()` runs `setInterval` - in other words, sets up a different task repeated each 1 sec. But you clearly need a single interval (as in the second snippet) - just continued at each step.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `init.bind(this, ++n)` returns a new function and that new function then returns a new function, and so on. There isn't just one `init` function running every second. So, there are new copies being created every second and they are, in turn, making more copies. There isn't just one `init` running by itself. The copies are getting "stacked" up.